# Replacing only pronoun, noun, verb and adjective in a sentence with its corresponding tags, how could I do it efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I have sentences and I want to replace only its Pronoun, nouns and adjective with its corresponding POS Tags. 
For example my sentence is :

> "I am going to the most beautiful city, Islamabad"

and want the result

> "PRP am VBG to the most JJ NN, NNP".

Comment: So what is the question? Where do you have difficulties?

Comment: how can I do it efficiently in Python NLTK? thanks @TomaszPlaskota

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> sent = "I am going to the most beautiful city, Islamabad"
>>> [pos if any(p for p in wanted_tags if pos.startswith(p)) else word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))]
['PRP', 'VBP', 'VBG', 'to', 'the', 'RBS', 'JJ', 'NN', ',', 'NNP']

>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
>>> [pos if any(p for p in wanted_tags if pos.startswith(p)) and word not in stoplist  else word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))]
['PRP', 'am', 'VBG', 'to', 'the', 'most', 'JJ', 'NN', ',', 'NNP']
```